# Closed form of a series

Tags: power-series, closed-form

Is there exist a closed form for the series of the form

> $$
> \sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]}(-a)^{k}\binom{n-k}{k}
> $$

where $0<a\leq1$. For example, we have 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]}\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^{k}\binom{n-k}{k}=\frac{n+1}{2^n}.
$$

Comment: @AhaanS.Rungta: Well, the question arises from the evaluation of determinant of tridiagonal matrix. One can obtain the determinant from two different perspectives, and thus find the formula(or identity) above. But a general method is absent.

Comment: This is a [Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Clearly, we can choose $\ds{b > 1}$ such that
$\ds{\verts{a \over z\pars{z + 1}} < 1}$ when $\ds{\verts{z} = b}$. Then,

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large
> \sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\floor{n/2}}\pars{-a}^{k}{n - k \choose k}}
> =\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\pars{-a}^{k}
> \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ b}
> {\pars{1 + z}^{n - k} \over z^{k + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ b}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z}\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
> \bracks{-\,{a \over z\pars{1 + z}}}^{k}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\oint_{\verts{z}}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z}
> {1 \over 1 + a/\bracks{z\pars{1 + z}}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}}{\pars{1 + z}^{n + 1} \over z^{2} + z + a}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\oint_{\verts{z}}{\pars{1 + z}^{n + 1} \over \pars{z - z_{-}}\pars{z - z_{+}}}\,
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,,\qquad z_{\pm} = {- 1 \pm \root{1 - 4a} \over 2}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large
\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\floor{n/2}}\pars{-a}^{k}{n - k \choose k}}
=\oint_{\verts{z}}\pars{1 + z}^{n + 1}
\pars{{1 \over z - z_{+}} - {1 \over z - z_{-}}}\,{1 \over z_{+} - z_{-}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&={1 \over \root{1 - 4a}}
\bracks{\pars{1 + z_{+}}^{n + 1} - \pars{1 + z_{-}}^{n + 1}}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large{1 \over \root{1 - 4a}}\bracks{
\pars{1 + \root{1 - 4a} \over 2}^{n + 1}-
\pars{1 - \root{1 - 4a} \over 2}^{n + 1}}}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much. It's the kind of answer I appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general formula (a CAS found it) $$\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}(-a)^{k}\binom{n-k}{k}=\frac{ (1+A)^{n+1}-(1-A)^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}A}$$ where $A=\sqrt{1-4a}$.

To get the formula for $a=\frac 14$, you will need to consider the limit.